# MySQL Date Handling Before a Given Date Table Join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

One contains information on a given reporting date and another has information on an incident date.

I’m trying to generate a list of the latest information before a given incident (i.e. if an incident occurred on 12/15/2015 and I have reports for 12/15/2014, 12/1/2015, and 1/12/2016, I want to pull the information for 12/1/2015 from that Data set.  If on the second row there is another incident that occurred on 1/13/2016 and I have the same data as above I only want to return the information on 1/12/2016).

Dates are in a different column than ID.

Tables are in the following format

```
ID -     DateV-                            ValueX
JAS    2017-12-15 00:00:00         3.45
```

I’ve tried running a query similar to below, but it only returns the first item ID-DateCombination not a list of all items.  I would even be fine with just the latest reporting date by incident ID.  That would give me enough to get the values I need.

```
Reporting Table - TableRep
Incident Table - TableInc

SELECT TableRep.ID, TableRep.DateV, TableRep.ValueX 
FROM TableRep 
INNER JOIN Table 
ON TableInc.DateP > (
SELECT Max(TableRep.DateV) FROM TableRep;);
```

I’ve narrowed it down to only records before a given date in the table, but I’m struggling to lose the dates other than the latest ones.

Essentially, I would like to pull the id and Date from TableInc and the first date before the date indicated in TableInc from TableRep for each record in TableInc.  Some IDs have multiple entries, so I can’t just pull them all and choose the max for each ID, that would only represent about 50% of the population.

Comment: Please don’t use numeric table names. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: look into the Having keyword. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx